# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2, ipad

i am trying to add splitview into my project code.
I understand that most of the SplitView project have their splitview loaded on the main window.

but i need to have other views before i come to the split view. That's the reason that i added split view to one of my view controller.

i have successfully added my split view.. but currently whenever i change the orientation of my ipad, **wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003** will be thrown on the debugging window and will have a lag time during the orientation change.

i have tried to look around for a solution but i failed.

anybody have any idea?

many many thanks!

p/s:i would like to upload my project code.. but i am not sure how to do it.. any tips will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Basically I believe that some UI elements (in my case, an alert box) was delaying some of the other UI elements in the split view to show up. I put my alert box in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method (it executes when a flag becomes true) so I no longer get the error (as all the elements are displayed by that point)

Hope the advice is useful for you. good luck.

Edward

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in Google and clicking the very first link revealed this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/17373-wait_fences-failed-receive-reply-10004003-a.html

You can upload your code to a filesharing website and post the link or copy the code into your question and format is accordingly using the "101010" button on top of the text view where you enter the question into.